# swift3 - Adding Exif information to images

Tags: ios8, swift3, xcode8

I am generating image file after processing the image. Location looks something like this
"/file:/Users/some_user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D4C78002-F842-465C-91BE-F7A61239975F/data/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0074.JPG"

I am trying to add meta information using swift3 using the following code

```
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: imageFile.path, isDirectory: false)

    guard let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(fileURL as CFURL, nil) else {
        return false
    }

    guard let properties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, nil) as NSDictionary? else {
        return false
    }

    let exifDictionary = (properties.object(forKey: kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary) as? NSMutableDictionary) ?? NSMutableDictionary()


    guard let sourceType = CGImageSourceGetType(source) else {
        return false
    }

    let imageData = NSMutableData()
    guard let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(imageData, sourceType, 1, nil) else {
        return false
    }
    ...
    CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destination, source, 0, newProperties)
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)
   imageData.write(toFile: imageFile.path, atomically: true)
```

I am getting nil for the following line but fileURL exists as mentioned above.  How can we get CGImageSource in the code

```
let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(fileURL as CFURL, nil)
```

Comment: Here is an answer in Swift 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132357/swift-custom-camera-save-modified-metadata-with-image/38134509#38134509