# Save pictures that was taken through the app's camera to device's camera roll with metadata

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, swift3

I have app that has an in-app camera that the user can take picture using it.

I want that when the user take a picture, the picture will be saved to the device's camera roll.

I've tried to do it with:

`UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToSave, nil, nil, nil)`

but then I realised it's not saving it with the metadata of the image (GPS and capture time).

My question is: how can I save the image with its metadata to the camera roll (Swift 3)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello this question might help you :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132357/swift-custom-camera-save-modified-metadata-with-image

Comment: @0ndre_ That's really complicated, and I can't understand what relates to my question and what doesn't. Is there any simpler and clearer way to do it? Just save a photo with GPS and time. Or can you please summarise me what should I do? Thanks

Comment: My answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/43375633/6431067) shows a Swift solution for how to save an image to the Camera Roll using the Photos API while preserving any changes made to the metadata (specifically adding GPS/capture time to the image).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save some exif, you can use [SimpleExif pod](https://github.com/Nikita2k/SimpleExif)

First create a ExifContainer:

```
ExifContainer *container = [[ExifContainer alloc] init];
```

and populate it with all requred data:

```
[container addUserComment:@"My data"];
[container addCreationDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-10000000]];
[container addLocation:locations[0]];
```

Then you can add this data to image:

```
NSData *imageData = [imageToSave addExif:container];
```

And Save

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([UIImage imageWithData:imageData], nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: And then how do I set the image itself?

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you explain me more about it?

Comment: on the code example you added you don't add the UIImage itself. Just its metadata

Comment: In your code:
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToSave, nil, nil, nil);

imageToSave is the UIImage itself

I add metadata to image in 

NSData *imageData = [imageToSave addExif:container];